# Installing RSA Archer with IIS with windows credentials not logging in

Tags: iis, archer, rsa-archer-grc

I have installed RSA Archer with IIS server on my windows server, Its working on localhost, but I am not able to login with windows creds.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions outlined in this article, https://community.rsa.com/t5/archer-platform-documentation/authentication-methods/ta-p/543852

But for when it comes time to modify the web.config file use this tool instead, https://community.rsa.com/t5/archer-blog/web-config-editor-3-0/ba-p/569351